# Google Map not rendering on subsequent page loads with Jquery Mobile (in rails)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, mobile, maps

I'm creating a mobile version of my site, coded in ruby on rails. I use the Cartographer plugin to generate google maps, and I'm using JQuery mobile. On the first page of my site, there is a google map which shows properly.
When I navigate through the site and back to the home page, the map does not show. I've done some research and I think it's because the javascript event that renders the map isn't firing. I found [this post](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/using-google-maps-with-jquery-mobile) that says "The page change event is pageshow" but I have no idea how to modify my code to reflect that. 
As per [this page](http://jquerymobile.com/test/experiments/google-maps/), I am loading the google maps js in the page header.
Help?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a late response but it is to do with page transitions when navigating between pages. The following article may shed more light on how to solve the problem: http://comdynamics.net/blog/468/jquery-mobile-with-google-maps/